# Giving numbers to each grid cell by rows in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, numbering, spatial-sort

I want to assign cell numbers to each grid cell (only having a point in the middle) beginning with 1 at the upper left corner, numbering consecutively by rows. The cells that I want to number are shown below.

Could you help me do that?

[image: Grid cells to be numbered]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Advanced level license of ArcGIS Desktop then I think the simplest way to do this is to:

1. Use the `Shape` field and `UL` as a `spatial_sort_method` in the [Sort](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort.htm) tool to sort the order of the polygons in your fishnet
2. Label using the polygon ID

If you only want to number the grid cells within your red polygon then you will probably want to perform a Clip prior to performing the spatial sort.

If you do not have an Advanced level license then you will need to write some non-trivial ArcPy code to emulate the spatial sort.